# Stop render from console in Blender

Tags: python, rendering, render, blender

I have a Blender operator that includes the following loop, and I would like to be able to stop the render when I press the Edc key.

When the operator goes into the loop the UI freezes until the renders are done, which could be a long time. So if I want to stop the render I have to close blender from the task manager (Win) or wait until render is complete.

```
for cam in cameras:
                if not cam.hide_render:
                    bpy.context.scene.camera = cam
                    img_path = os.path.join(output_directory, f"{cam.name}.png")

                    if context.scene.use_multiview_override:
                        bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = img_path
                        bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
                        images.append(Image.open(bpy.context.scene.render.filepath))
                    else:
                        if os.path.exists(img_path):
                            images.append(Image.open(img_path))
                        else:
                            bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = img_path
                            bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
                            images.append(Image.open(bpy.context.scene.render.filepath))
```

I have looked everywhere, including Blender API without luck. I tried to implement a modal operator but I am very new to coding and perhaps that's why I couldn't make it work. It would either not render at all or not stop the render process. Saw a similar question but the answer was not something I could implement in my script. Pardon my lack of knowledge